# How to create an executable .exe file from a .m file

Tags: matlab, executable

I was wondering if there is a way to create a '.exe' file from  ' .m' file in MATLAB, such that it can be run in machine which does not have MATLAB (like it can be done in C, C++).

I know writing a MATLAB function is one way, but I am not sure if it can run in machine without MATLAB.

Also I would like to hide my code and just create a script which can be run by a user using his own data files.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Matlab Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) is the standard way to do this. `mcc` is the command.  The Matlab Runtime is required to run the programs; I'm not sure if it can be directly integrated with the executable or not.

Comment: One thing to note - this is a toolbox that you have to pay extra for.

Comment: Good point.  I wasn't sure because I've always worked on University installs that included it.

Comment: The Matlab Compiler is pricey - it will set you back $5K.

Comment: ...and deploytool provides an option to include the MCR library with your standalone executable.

Answer (score 9):

If you have MATLAB Compiler installed, there's a GUI option for compiling. Try entering

```
deploytool
```

in the command line. Mathworks does a pretty good job documenting how to use it in this video tutorial: http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/compiler/deploytool/index.html

Also, if you want to include user input such as choosing a file or directory, look into

```
uigetfile % or uigetdir if you need every file in a directory
```

for use in conjunction with

```
guide
```

Comment: does the GUI or figure production compile successfully ?

Comment: @Vass, yes it will compile GUIs too.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
mcc -m yourfile
```

Also see `help mcc`

Comment: Thanks , it works great, but not sure if it works in non matlab installed machines.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is more of a data analysis routine (vs. visualization / GUI), try [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). It's free and many of its functions are compatible with MATLAB. (Not 100% but maybe 99.5%.)

Comment: 99.32% of statistics are made up on the spot

Answer (score 2):

```
mcc -?
```

explains that the syntax to make *.exe (Standalone Application) with *.m is:

```
 mcc -m <matlabFile.m>
```

For example:

```
mcc -m file.m
```

will create file.exe in the curent directory.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be possible to compile Matlab to C with older versions of Matlab. Check out other tools that Matlab comes with.

Newest Matlab code can be exported as a Java's jar or a .Net Dll, etc. You can then write an executable against that library - it will be obfuscated by the way. The users will have to install a freely available Matlab Runtime.

Like others mentioned, mcc / mcc.exe is what you want to convert matlab code to C code.

Answer (score 1):

The "StandAlone" method to compile .m file (or files) requires a set of Matlab published library (.dll) files on a target (non-Matlab) platform to allow execution of the compiler generated .exe.

Check MATLAB main site for their compiler products and their limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a non-matlab software for direct compilation of m-files ([TMC Compiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tmc-m-files-to-c-compiler/)). This is an open-source converter of m-files projects to C. The compiler produces the C code that may be linked with provided open-source run-time library to produce a stand-alone application. The library implements a set of build-in functions; the linear-algebra operations use LAPACK code. It is possible to expand the set of the build-in functions by custom implementation as described in the documentation.

Comment: and does it work for various aspects of MATLAB that depends upon the OS like the GUI APIs?