# Re : Open Matlab function from command line linux

Tags: linux, matlab, command-line, command-line-arguments

I got the answer from the following question. It asks me to create a bash file. The question is in the title

[How to call MATLAB functions from the Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001183/how-to-call-matlab-functions-from-the-linux-command-line)

Thus I tried the following code, as given in the answer.

```
    b_exec=matlab
    X="localize(r,q)"
    echo ${X} > matlab_command_rq.m
    cat matlab_command_rq.m 
    ${matlab_exec} -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash < matlab_command_rq.m
    rm matlab_command_rq.m
```

The original code in the answer was

```
    matlab_exec=matlab
    X="${1}(${2})"
    echo ${X} > matlab_command_${2}.m
    cat matlab_command_${2}.m
    ${matlab_exec} -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash < matlab_command_${2}.m
    rm matlab_command_${2}.m
```

In the explanation, they mentioned that $1 was function and $2 was inputs. correspondingly, I replaced it with my function 'localize' and inputs (r,q)

But I got the following error

```
    localize(r,q)
    ./matlab_batcher.sh: 5: ./matlab_batcher.sh: -nojvm: not found
```

The echo seems to be working. But I really do not know what is happening after that. Could you please help me and tell me the right way to call the matlab function with its arguments???

I called it using the following statement

```
   sh ./matlab_batcher.sh localize r q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `b_exec` back to `matlab_exec`, or you need to change

```
${matlab_exec} -nojvm ...
```

to

```
${b_exec} -nojvm ...
```

Either way, you need to make it consistent.

Comment: could you please tell me wat you mean by saying I should make it consistent? And the way am calling the function, is it the correct way?

Comment: am getting the same error even after the change. :(. please help me here.!

Comment: I mean that you can't name your variable `b_exec` and then reference `matlab_exec` (which is then undefined). As for how you're calling it, since you hardcoded the function name and arguments into your script, you can just do `sh ./matlab_batcher.sh`.

Comment: You're still getting `-nojvm: not found`? That seems unlikely. You should double-check your work. Failing that, post exactly what you now have.

Comment: no, actually am getting this.

./matlab_batcher.sh: 5: ./matlab_batcher.sh: matlab: not found
. Sorry for incomplete comment.

Comment: That means `matlab` isn't in your search path. The easiest thing to do is just use the full path to `matlab`, e.g. set `matlab_exec=/path/to/matlab` (wherever that is on your system). If you don't know, you'll have to ask your local support over there.

Comment: Thanks a Ton. That worked. Another last doubt!! If I have to pass arguments from command line, what am I supposed to do? Instead of Hardcoding

Comment: Then you should go back to the original version of the code and make a call like `sh ./matlab_batcher.sh localize "r,q"`.

Comment: this function localize(r,q) should be in the same directory of this bash file??

Comment: It can be in any directory where MATLAB searches for functions, but the same directory would be one of those places.

Comment: Wow. Looks like am learning a lot here, thanks to your patience. How do I know the directories where matlab searches for? Should I add them in search path, in matlab settings!

Comment: That's actually something you can easily search for on the web.

Comment: ok ok. sorry for asking everything. I have another doubt. I will post that as a question. If you know, please help me. I will try searching in google as well.