# How to call MATLAB functions with matrices as arguments (not just numbers or strings) from the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, matlab, matrix, command-line

Currently I call can only functions with string or integer arguments using this script

```
#!/bin/sh

matlab_exec=matlab
X="${1}(${2})"
echo ${X} > matlab_command_${2}.m
cat matlab_command_${2}.m
${matlab_exec} -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash < matlab_command_${2}.m
rm matlab_command_${2}.m
```

However it only accepts strings or integers. To call it I would run this command

```
./run funtions arg1,arg2
```

How could I make it so it would take a matrix but through the command line

i.e matrix [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

Comment: [This link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97204-how-can-i-pass-input-parameters-when-running-matlab-in-batch-mode-in-windows) seems to have some ideas.

Comment: @MatthewGunn That link is Windows only.

Comment: @rayryeng I hope people can replace /r with -r when in a unix environment.

Comment: @MatthewGunn you're expecting too much! :)

Comment: @rayryeng lol, and unfortunately, you're probably right !

Comment: @MatthewGunn :D.  BTW, I'm not sure if you're up for it, but we've had a MATLAB chat room going for a while: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave - whenever you like, drop by and say hello.  It's nice to see a new active MATLAB user around.  They're few and far in between!

Comment: @rayryeng Hey, I noticed you marked this question as a duplicate but the one that you linked doesn't explain how to used matrices as arguments. Would you know how to do that in matlab or where it was answered?

Comment: @TheEnigma I thought it did.  In that case, follow Matthew Gunn's advice: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97204-how-can-i-pass-input-parameters-when-running-matlab-in-batch-mode-in-windows - Replace `/r` with `-r` as you're using Linux.

Comment: @TheEnigma This post also will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001183/how-to-call-matlab-functions-from-the-linux-command-line

Comment: @rayryeng used the same script to call matlab scripts but they don't accept matrices