# Matlab - run file without opening GUI, then quit

Tags: linux, unix, matlab

I want Matlab to run some .m file, which writes to a text file. I don't want the GUI to launch, and I don't want the command line interpreter to run. I've got

```
matlab -nodisplay -r myfile
```

But this still runs the interpreter. What options should I be using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

matlab needs to interpreter to run your commands. you can always end your file with `quit` to make matlab exit again when finished with your calculations

Answer (score 4):

If you need to execute a matlab script you can do `matlab -nodisplay < script.m`.  If you want to call a matlab function, you can do `matlab -nodisplay -r "foo(); quit"`.  IIRC, in both cases matlab should exit once it is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile `myfile` into a standalone program and run that instead.  Use Matlab's compiler `mcc` for that (if you have it), more information is provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926089/how-to-create-a-executable-exe-file-from-m-file).