# How can I pass two matrices as arguments in a matlab executable?

Tags: matlab, arguments, executable

For example in MatLab, command line I use:

```
functionname([1 2 3;4 5 6],[1 3 2;7 9 8])
```

I get a result.  But, on windows using `cmd`:

```
functionname "[1 2 3;4 5 6]" "[1 3 2;7 9 8])
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What result are you expecting?  Does this function output something to the console, or did you expect a return value to be magically printed?

Comment: The function takes two matrices as arguments, make same calculations and return a result. I tested it directly on the matlab command line ,it works. But after creating the executable, I can't find how I can pass two matrices as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on [How to create a executable .exe file from .m file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926089/how-to-create-a-executable-exe-file-from-m-file).

You should use `mcc -m yourfile` and it's only work with Matlab installed machines.
One other way could be using `.dll` and running it via Visual Studio.

Comment: I've already created the exe file, the problem is that I can't find how I can pass two matrices as arguments. For two numeric values for example i can use 
functionname 4 5
but functionname "[1 2 3;4 5 6]" "[1 3 2;7 9 8]) doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the arguments to numerical on demand:

In functionname(a, b), add

```
if ischar(a)
  a = eval(a);
end

if ischar(b)
  b = eval(b);
end
```

Now functionname() can be called with numerical arguments and from the command line with string arguments:

```
functionname "[1 2 3;4 5 6]" "[1 3 2;7 9 8]"
```

Note that eval() does the opposite of mat2str().